# Error while creating Elasticsearch table from Hive table - HiveAccessControlException Permission Denied: user does not have [RWSTORAGE] privilege

Tags: elasticsearch, hive

I have a *Hive* table that I want to convert to an Elasticsearch index. When I try to create the Elasticsearch index, I am getting the error shown as below.

I will appreciate any help in debugging this issue. I have checked the Ranger policies but it did not help me resolve the issue.

Here is the error message:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED:
> HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [ab_user] does not
> have [RWSTORAGE] privilege on [esstoragehandler://upsert/////false/]
> (state=42000,code=40000)

*A note on Ranger*: In this case, I do not have access to Ranger directly, and I have to ask someone else to do this for me. I requested for following permissions on Ranger, please let me know if this is correct.

```
Elasticsearch StoragerHandler policy:
Storage Type: EsStorageHandler
Storage Url: esstoragehandler://upsert/<ES server ip>/<index key>/<index name>/<ES Port>/false/
```

Thanks in advance!